# Why perform case sensitive comparison on JOIN make query so slow

Tags: mysql

I have following query ,and I want to perform case-sensitive on JOIN comparision condition :

```
SELECT kousei.kousei_hin_id,shohin.shohin_id, hf.KOSCASSU, hf.MSTLINNO 
FROM sc.HINMTF hf 
LEFT OUTER JOIN m_kousei_hin kousei ON BINARY hf.HINCD  = kousei.kousei_hin_code  
LEFT OUTER JOIN m_shohin shohin ON BINARY hf.KOSHINCD  = shohin.shohin_code  ;
```

If I don't use `BINARY` ,querying time is short , but with `BINARY` it very very slow

I tried another way such as `collate` .But still have no good result , query time still very long

Please help me about this

Comment: why my question get a down vote ,please tell me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Well, the conversion on the fly takes ages and (I think) no index can be used.

Your best bet is, that you have your tables set up with collation set to a binary one, at least for the column you want to compare.

Here's an example how it would work:

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE a
    (`a` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin)
;

INSERT INTO a
    (`a`)
VALUES
    ('a'), ('B')
;

CREATE TABLE b
    (`b` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin)
;

INSERT INTO b
    (`b`)
VALUES
    ('A'), ('B')
;
```

**Query:**

```
select a, b from a join b on a.a = b.b;
```

**Result:**

```
| a | b |
|---|---|
| B | B |
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaa66f/1/0)